# prisma, unable to get my Enums from @prisma/client

Tags: node.js, prisma, nest

I'm using prismaJs as my ORM and i have some enum that i need to use. Right now i have 4 different enums in my schema, when i try to access them with

---

import { difficulty } from "@prisma/client";
it gives me this error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'difficulty'.

---

for some reason i'm able to access the enum type situation, but not the other enums that i have.
[image]

my other enums:
[image]

I tried to delete the migrations folder and use the command npx prisma migrate dev, but it made no difference.

---

When i access import { $Enums } from "@prisma/client"; my $Enums only have the situation enum.

---

packages versions: "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1", "prisma": "^5.4.2", "@nestjs/common": "^10.2.6", "@nestjs/core": "^10.2.6".

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It seems you have to have used the enum in a model before it will be generated in the index.d.ts file.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13382).

Answer (score 1):

when you use prisma it generates models for themselves and migrations for database
`npx prisma generate`  it generate models for you
`npx prisma migrate dev` it creates migration
when you write enum it creates migration but until you use it in table models in prisma it doesn't create enum for your working environment when you use this enum inside table column after that you can import enum from prisma client